# EF 6 - Can not add views and table to my edmx

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

I'm using EF6 database first, VS 2017, SQL Sever 2016. I can add stored procedure to the edmx but everytime I try to add a table or a view I get a NullReferenceException.

Maybe there is something wrong with my visual studio configuration because it is an existing project. I guess the person who created the model had no problem. I tryied to create a new edmx and I had no problem to add views and table to it. But as its an existing project, I prefer not to drop/create the existing model.
I want to find a way to update the existing model.

Comment: Did you use the update-database command to make sure your code-model fits your database?

Comment: yes I did and I can drop/insert stored procedures from my database

Comment: In this case, what did you mean with add a table? if you add a table you have to do a database migration again

Comment: I droped the edmx and created a new one. Thanks for having tried to help.